# Drupal Scheduler module cron

Tags: drupal, cron, scheduler

I'm using the [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) module to publish and unpublish my content at certain times, however I would like to get a more frequent publish than using the Drupal cron itself.

There is an option within the scheduler for using a lightweight cron specifically for scheduler but I have never written a cron task before and I just simply do not know what I am doing, it gives me an example of how I would write one which is

- - - - - /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://example.com/scheduler/cron"

To make sure I am getting this correctly, would this line (modified to point to my address) go into a file called cron.php?

I have tried doing the above but it doesnt appear to be publishing my content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll need to add this line to your crontab on the server. Talk to your hosting provider, they should be able to help you.

If you're running your own server, run this command from in the shell:

```
crontab -e
```

And add your line last in that file.

See [here for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: Ok, I didn't think it would be as simple as a php file, it didn't look like PHP I was writing. I'll try to get in touch with the service provider, I assume webfaction and rackspace will have the capacity to do this quite easily

Comment: Correct, Rackspace can set up your crontab, server-side. Meanwhile, maybe familiarize yourself with how Drupal cron actually works, as well as how to make it more granular, for example using Elysia cron (some caveats apply.)